# div align on the left of centered div

Tags: html, css

I need to do next thing:

i need on div to be centered in the middle of the page

```
.container12
    {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

and i need another div whose class name is "leftDiv" which will be on the left side of div with class "container12". .leftDiv should float on the left side of .container12 and have width from end of the page to the left side of the .container12.

Here is the picture:
[image]

How to write class for leftDiv?

Comment: You should post what you've tried - eg your `leftDiv`, and any other css classes you've worked on. And an HTML example. Preferably in a Fiddle or Snippet. You are being downvoted because, as it stands, this is essentially asking someone to do the work for you, not asking the community for help solving a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I totally agree with you. I'm going to put some code into my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple method you could use based on your question:

```
.container12 {
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}
.leftDiv {
  width:25%;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

Remember that floats pull elements out of the flow of the page, so you need to apply a `clearfix` to the centered `div` to keep elements aligned properly.

## [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/GgjjXr)

Answer (score 0):

add float:left to each element and they should line up side by side. Something like this -

```
.container12
        {
        max-width: 960px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        float:left;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }

    .leftDiv {
        width: 40%; 
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        float:left;

    }
```

Make sure to play around with the widths etc and you should get what you need.